# Reading registry value's data with spaces

Tags: batch-file, registry

I am making a program. When installed, It will run a batch file which needs to know where the application folder is.

The installation wizard software I am using creates a registry key that represents the program's path, but "Program Files" has a space in it, so the batch output will be "C:\Program"

My current script is:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set KEY_NAME="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\MarksRTZ\AV"
set VALUE_NAME=DataPath

FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
    set ValueName=%%A
    set ValueType=%%B
    set ValueValue=%%C
)

if defined ValueName (
    echo data "%ValueValue%"
    echo name "%ValueName%"
    echo type "%ValueType%"
) else (
    echo Not found
)
```

The `DataPath` value is set to `[APPDIR]\data` on installation, `[APPDIR]` being the location the user selected.

But like I said, that script will always output `C:\Program` if [APPDIR] was set to something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\MarksRTZ\AV\` in the installer (Which is actually the default)

How can I fix this?

I will also note; the batch file isn't the real program, It's going to be the simple script that launches the program in the correct working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Next code snipped should work with `tokens=1-2*` and even with `setlocal DISABLEEXTENSIONS`:

```
rem ensure %ValueName% is not visible as it could be defined already! 
set "ValueName="

FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1-2*" %%A IN (
    `REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
    set "ValueName=%%A"
    set "ValueType=%%B"
    set "ValueValue=%%C"
)

if defined ValueName (
    echo data "%ValueValue%"
    echo name "%ValueName%"
    echo type "%ValueType%"
) else (
    echo Not found
)
```

Resources:

- `FOR /F` [Loop command: against the results of another command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html);
- `SETLOCAL` [Set options to control the visibility of environment variables in a batch file](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)